# Client not handshaken client should reconnect

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I researched all over the internet and nothing found useful about this problem.I am using socket.io here is my code

And this is my client code:

```
io.transports = ['xhr-polling'];
var socket=io.connect("http://domain.com:8427/",{'sync disconnect on unload': true});
```

When I look the log files,I see too many client not handshaken client should reconnect errors.And sometimes socket sometimes firing "disconnect" event when user still on the page.I do not know whether there is relevance about this errors and disconnects.

I tried to install cluster hub but it is freezing.How can I resolve it ?

Comment: Start by moving most of your `var` declarations to *inside* the `connection` event handler. You're overwriting them with each new incoming `socket.io` connection now.

Comment: @robertklep I'll try it but are u sure is this resolve the problem ? I am not sure.

Comment: No, I'm not sure if it will solve this particular problem, but it will solve all sorts of potentially undefined behaviour.

Comment: @robertklep I tried your suggestion but problem is still same

Comment: Even I get `Client not handshaken client should reconnect` warning on my Linux server. Anyone of you, who knows when and why this happens. Configuration: `node - version 0.12.7`, `restify - version 2.8.1`
`socket.io - version 0.9.16`